# How to reduce image resolution of an image in a realistic way

Tags: image, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Deep learning has shown [quite remarkable progress in image super resolution](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/SRCNN.html) lately. But I fear that the data generation method is not realistic enough, hence my question.

**Background:**

The basic premise of applying deep learning to the problem is as following:
A low resolution image is generated from a high resolution image, using simple downsampling. The low resolution image or alternatively an interpolated image are fed into a neural network and a high resolution image is estimated.

**Question:**

The classic method of down-sampling the data produces some [pretty significant results](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/47j3p3/bb8_image_superresolved/) What I fear is that in this example, the neural network simply learns to estimate the inverse of this specific interpolation as best as it can. But since resolution degradation in real world in usually not consisting of a downsample and then an upsample with specific interpolation scheme, I believe this algorithm does not generalize as well to real world examples.

So my question is:
Is there a better, more realistic, way to reduce the resolution of an image than naive down-sampling, so we can better train and test the performance of the algorithm?

Comment: What is "real-world resolution degradation," anyway?

Comment: i've been thinking something akin to using some form of kernel averaging than a naive average down sample

Comment: there is no such thing as "real world resolution degradation" (in the sense there is no single entity). There are plenty of different ways image can be downsampled in "real world", in particular what you call "naive down sampling" is used in many real life applications. If you have doubts how well it generalizes to other compression techniques - test it first, and then thing about fixing if it really fails. Do not try to fix something that is not broken :-)